# How to change the meta title of Product reviews in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.6

I cant provide any code because that is part of the question, but I am sure if you guide me in the right direction I can paste the code from the files you tell me.

I enabled product reviews on my site:
However the product page title and the product review page title its the same and its giving me lots of duplicate pages for my SEO efforts.

examples:
normal page
http://www.theprinterdepo.com/hp-laser-p2015dn-printer-cb368a

same product review page 
http://www.theprinterdepo.com/review/product/list/id/1133/

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any feature out of the box that allows you to specify different titles for product review pages.  I could be wrong though?

So, that leaves two methods you can use to achieve this.

1. Core block override
2. Event/Observer

I would opt for option 2 here.  Even with this option there are still various ways to achieve this.  Here is one of them...

So, once you have created your module, you will need to declare the observer in your config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

    <!-- other config xml -->

    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_render_before_review_product_list>
                <observers>
                    <productmeta>
                        <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controller_action_layout_render_before_review_product_list</method>
                    </productmeta>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_render_before_review_product_list>
        </events>
    </frontend>

    <!-- other config xml -->

</config>
```

Then your observer would be similar to this...

```
<?php

class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * @pram Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function controller_action_layout_render_before_review_product_list(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {   
        $title = "Your new page title";
        Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setData('title', $title);
    }
}
```